# How to set the factor of true classifications of training set of the knn test on a given learning set to predict class of the data?

Tags: r, k-nearest-neighbour

From the well-known dataset iris I want to predict the species of flowers given a the length of their sepals and petals and their width.

The data frame looks like :

[image]

Having :

```
xapp <- c(data[1,40],data[51:90,],data[101:140,])
xtest <- c(data[41:50,],data[91:100,],data[141:150,])
```

I wrote :

```
matriceKnn <- knn(xapp,
                  xtest,
                  cl, 
                  k = 1, 
                  l = 0, 
                  prob = FALSE, 
                  use.all = TRUE)
```

But I don't know what to write for cl, factor of true classifications of training set. Furthermore I'm not sure of k and l.

I tried to give the species, as a factor of true classifications of training set:

```
knn(train = xapp,   #you only need residual.sugar you said so just use that
    test=xtest,       #again test is the residual.sugar
    cl=as.factor(xapp[['Species']]) , #your cl argument is quality
    k=1, l=0, prob=FALSE, use.all=TRUE)
```

But it told me it wasn't the good length. So, finally, I tried the following function to fit with the length :

```
knn(train = xapp,   #you only need residual.sugar you said so just use that
    test=xtest,       #again test is the residual.sugar
    cl = as.factor(c(rep("s",3),rep("v",3),rep("z",4))),
    k=1, l=0, prob=FALSE, use.all=TRUE)
```

And it answered me :

```
Error in knn(train = xapp, test = xtest, cl = as.factor(c(rep("s", 3),  : 
  dims of 'test' and 'train' differ
```

Therefore **how can I apply a knn test, and more specifical how to specify the class, on a given learning set to predict class of the data ?**

Comment: You question and your code do not agree.  You write about the iris data but your code uses xapp and mentions residual sugar. Please align the code with the question.

Comment: @GSW Indeed, I updated how I did used iris in `xapp` and `xtest`